# How can we edit content inside textarea feild?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

Here i am using django 3.0.3/python and jquery for front-end,well my question is that i simple want to add some styling inside the textarea , Most of people are familiar with medium , I simple want to convert my blog form to the form like medium , right know my blog form looks like:

[image]

and I simple want to change it like :
[image]

I also want all these following tools during writing a blog:

[image]

Well i am not saying that give all the code in the answers, I just want to know the steps which i need to make and the things which i will be going to use to make. I will extremely thankful to all of you who will answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

Medium doesn't really have extra style inside the textarea.
You only need to create a div and put inputs, textarea inside without borders.

Something like these :

```css
#container {
  width: 100%
}
input {
  border:unset;
  width: 100%;
  font-size:  2em;
}
textarea {
  border: unset;
  width: 100%
}
#container > input:focus, #container > textarea:focus {
  border: unset;
  outline: unset
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input placeholder="Title"/>
  <textarea rows="15" cols="65"></textarea>
</div>
```